# how to call a method in class just once even if the object for the class is created numerous times

Tags: java, spring-boot

I want to set the time limit using a method:

```
setTimeLimit()
```

But, this `setTimeLimit()` is present inside a class, and the object is created as the list is iterated like below:

```
result.forEach(item -> {
    MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
    myClass.setSomething(item.myVariable);
});
```

`setTimeLimit()` is called inside `setSomething()`, as the list iterates that many times `setTimeLimit()` is called, which I want to call just once during the entire iteration. How can I achieve this or approach to this problem?

Task is to set the URL timelimit for all the images.

I tried autowiring the constructor of `MyClass` and calling `setTimeLimit()` in the constructor, but I think `setTimeLimit()` is called when the dependency is injected, so I don't want this to set during DI.

Comment: lookup: static methods and static variables. alternatively you can create a separate class which will be responsible for this timeout.

Comment: Could you please post the code of MyClass?

Comment: public class MyClass {
            // expiry time of the url in Linux epoch form (seconds since january 1970)
         static String expiryTime;
        public String setSomething(String myVariable) throws Exception {
            setTimeLimit();
            return signedUrl;
        }
        private void setTimeLimit() {
            long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
            // expire in a minute!
            long expiredTimeInSeconds = (now + 60 * 1000L) ;
            expiryTime = expiredTimeInSeconds + "";
        }
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should try something like this:

```java
private void setTimeLimit(Object timeLimit) {
  if (Objects.isNull(this.timeLimit)) {
    this.timeLimit = timeLimit;
  }
}
```

However, I recommend that you change the class structure to initialize only once for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

A setter shouldn't care when or how many times it's called externally. If you don't want to expose the `setTimeLimit()` outside of the class, and you only want it called once per iteration, then what about accepting a List of "something" rather than a single "something".

ie.

```
public class MyClass {

    public void setSomethings(List<String> somethings) {
        setTimeLimit();
        somethings.forEach(this::setSomething);
    }

    private void setSomething(String something) {
        // ...
    }

    private void setTimeLimit() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

This way MyClass has the control it wants, without breaking functional relationship between MyClass and it's consumers.

Comment: thanks for the solution,i like your suggestion, but as this is the common class and i have to just send the list<someDto> which has image files in each someDto of the List , So i prefer sending just the someDto.imageFile by looping .and sending to the static setSomething(// setLimitTime() and do something with with the someDto.imageFile) as per the suggestion provided by yeahseol